# "0" in reputation history when accepting a self-answer with an upvote on the same day

Tags: bug, design, accepted-answer, self-answer, reputation-history

When accepting a self-answer, this usually causes a blank entry in your reputation history (see the bottom circle below). However, when that happens on a day when you also get an upvote on that answer, it's shown as a white 0 on a green background. The aggregated entry is also white on a green background. You can see this in [my reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=8&StartDate=2020-08-22%2011:45:57Z) on January 21st this year.

[image]

I'd expect it to look like this:

[image]